# Jquery Lib. function only for deleting the contents of drop-down

Tags: jquery, function, static-libraries

In internet I searched a lot., and cannot find a predefined jquery library function for deleting **only the contents of the Drop-down box**,excluding the information option. But all I can find is  [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) which empties all the contents including the label.

Hence I wrote my own function as below.,

```
$.fn.emptyTheContents = function () {
    var dropDownInfo = $(this).children('option[value=""]').text();
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).append($('<option/>', {
        value: "",
        text: dropDownInfo
    }));
};
```

For example, on every country change in a form, I will call as.,

```
$("#state").emptyTheContents(); // Where <select your state> is the common info.
//Binding of corresponding states using AJAX request.
```

My question is **It is very common requirement for a dropdown box to empty only the contents,by excluding the information option**, But why there is no library function for that?

Comment: What do you meant by label? Do you want to remove all the options excluding the 1st option?

Comment: @DownVoter Please comment for voting this to close.

Comment: @DON yes the 1st information option like "Select any country"

Comment: did you check http://api.jquery.com/empty/? `$(dropdown).empty();`

Comment: @andreister   But if there is a function like .emptyTheContents() then that would be highly readable na? Bcz., this function will be used by many at more common ways frequently

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT I see your points - updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use that specific logic extensively on *your project* then surely you can create and use a separate method.

However, I understand your question as why it's not included in jquery library. The answer is that, from a library designer perspective, this task is pretty narrow and can be solved with already existing library functions.

Eg:

```
$("#state").children('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

The goal of a library designer is to provide as few methods as possible to solve as much  problems as possible. You don't want "methods for everything" because nobody will remember how to use the API. Instead, you strive to find a balance between flexibility vs ease of use, and on this way some solutions have eventually to drop out.

If you want to read more about API design specifically in javascript, check out

- [Secrets of Awesome JavaScript API Design](http://webstandardssherpa.com/reviews/secrets-of-awesome-javascript-api-design)
- [Designing Better JavaScript APIs](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/09/designing-javascript-apis-usability/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying that there is an `option` element which contains a description for the drop down box. So you want to remove all the `option` elements except the first one. This is easy to do:

```
 $('#state option').slice(1).remove();
```

- [`$.fn.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) reduces the selection just like `Array.prototype.slice` does. `.slice(1)` means "remove the first element from the selection`.
- [`$.fn.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) removes the selected elements from the DOM.

This will therefore result in only the first element being left in the drop down. It's not that common a requirement really, which is why it is not a standard jQuery function. Not least as it is so easy to do, as you see above.

[Here is a jsFiddle showing this code.](http://jsfiddle.net/uyHme/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one...

```
$("#state").html("").append("<option value=''>Select Any</option>");
```

Comment: Creating a new element is a very slow way to go about this task and completely unnecessary.